# Adding elements to div

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am using microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community and I am creating website in ASP.NET Web site (Razor v3).

I would like to create a "box"(div element?) that would be filled from database as attached in pic. The circle is meant to delete element from database when clicked, but it is not the current topic. 
How can I use my variable userCitiesSQL to insert the elements into div? Should I use var userCities = new WebGrid(source: userCitiesSQL); or something similar?
[image: Expl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>

   @foreach(var row in userCitiesSql)
   {
       <span>@row.Name</span>
   }

</div>
```

See this article : [enter link description here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data)